PTK and GTK where are they stored?
So I know for unicast traffic PTK is used to encrypt and obtain ciphertext; and for multicast traffic GTK is used to encrypt and obtain ciphertext. I know PTK is produced at a 4 way handshake, and also the router provides the GTK on the 3rd way of the handshake.
And more importantly, depending on the network, these keys are changed at hour intervals for further protection.
In my operating system, Windows and Ubuntu, I want to know where PTK and GTK are stored. I want to make a test for fun and take PTK/GTK from my local device; and use an outsider device to encrypt packets with the keystreams and send packets to the network.
I assume they would be stored in the kernel, but where exactly? Is it possible anyhow to retrieve them from the OS?
so Pair Transient Key should be a 64 byte key, and needs to have a store in the OS.

Your 802.11 hardware contains an AES engine where the work of AES-CCMP (WPA2) encryption and decryption is done. So even if you have an OS-level mechanism like wpa_supplicant to do the handshakes, there's no reason for the OS to retain a copy of those keys; those keys just need to be passed back down to the 802.11 chip so its built-in AES hardware engine can do its job. It seems to me that it would be best practice to NOT keep a copy of those keys in system memory or storage. Ideally those keys should be given to the 802.11 hardware and then deleted from system memory so they can't be leaked.

Interesting, @Spiff so there is no actual way to read them. Even trying to read from the hardware would be very effortful.
